htmx insert multiple table rows
I'm using Django, if that makes any difference. Anyway, I have this tbody element in my template:
            <tbody
               id="log-stream-table-body"
               hx-get="{% url 'pages:log_stream_rows' %}?last_ts={{ last_log_ts }}"
               hx-trigger="every 30s"
               hx-target="this"
               hx-swap="afterbegin"
            >
               {% include "pages/_home_log_stream_rows.html" with log_stream=log_stream %}
            </tbody>

The url it's pointing to returns this template snippet (which is actually pages/_home_log_stream_rows.html used in the include above):
{% for log in log_stream %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ log.ts|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u" }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.process }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.source }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.message }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

<div
    id="log-stream-hyperscript"
    hx-swap-oob="outerHTML"
    data-log-ts="{{ last_log_ts }}"
></div>

The problem is that I'm returning multiple tr elements at the top level, so the whole thing just fails.
I can wrap it in a <template> tag, and it works, but of course then nothing is visible. Wrapping in anything else (div, andother tbody) just breaks the display in different ways.
How can I group these multiple tr elements so that htmx adds them in correctly at the top of my table?

I don’t understand why HTMX behaves this way, but I got it to work with the response looking like this, i.e. using oob-swaps for both things:
<tbody hx-swap-oob="afterbegin:#log-stream-table-body">
    <tr>
        <td>{DateTime.Now}</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{r.Next()}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{DateTime.Now}</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{DateTime.Now}</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<div id="log-stream-hyperscript"
     hx-swap-oob="outerHTML"
     data-log-ts="{DateTime.Now}">{DateTime.Now}</div>


(This is test data using ASP.Net Core, I don’t have a Python/Django server here)
Using the latest HTMX 2.0.0, but not sure that’s relevant.

That's ... Not intuitive :) thanks though! I've finished for the day now, but will try this tomorrow.

OK, couldn't quite get that to work whether I left the tbody in the main template or moved it all to the htmx snippet. I've actually solved this this morning by finding another way to handle the timestamp and doing away with the oob stuff. Going to mark this as the right answer though because it's just a little odd and I'd never have thought of it :D

In my test the tbody is in the main page AND the htmx response. Htmx removes it for some reason. I guess it could be anything, I just used tbody cause it's a table.

Makes sense, but when I had it in both places it seemed to empty out the table when the htmx call was made. I think the problem is "table weirdness" rather than specifically htmx.
